# Python + Webkit-based GUI?

Tags: javascript, python, html, css

Is it possible to create a python script (eg. `main.py`) which creates the `GUI window`, which loads a `.html` file (with necessary `css` and possibly `javascript`), and have this `.html` file GUI interact with the `main.py`?

For example, in the `.html file` the user might click a button, which needs to interact with a function in the `main.py` file, and return a result in the `.html` file (python probably cannot edit the `html dom`, but may return a result the `javascript` can?).

I read `PyQt5` can create a `webview` (load html files locally or externally), but I need it to interact with python for returning results.

Thanks!

Comment: Yes, you can achieve it eg. with pyQT5 package. It can create window apps and also execute JavaScript.

Comment: You can also try iPython to do it- whole Jupyter notebook package is made on it and there JavaScript in browser talks to python kernel. But this is actually backend as in regular Web server, so why not simply use Django, web2py or pyramid?

Comment: I would use a simple micro-framework as a server (serve on `localhost:8080` or something like that) and when you run the server have it automatically open the page in your default browser. I suggest bottlepy or flask as a good, simple microframework. For interaction from server to client, you will need to have forms or use AJAX. http://bottlepy.org

Comment: Also look into [CEFPython](https://github.com/cztomczak/cefpython), it can do everything mentioned in your question.